# onActivityResult not called from main class

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a problem with my application.I have an activity called ExperimentView which has an inner class called FrameRoll which implements Runnable.

```
public class ExperimentView extends Activity implements OnClickListener,{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      //Other stuff
      //Call the gpshandler activity
      gpsCall();
    }

    public void gpsCall() {
     if (gpsEnabled.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {

        Intent gpsHandler = new Intent(ExperimentView.this,
                GpsHandler.class);
        startActivityForResult(gpsHandler,
                GPSHANDLER_ACTIVITY_RETURN);
finish();

       }
  }
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     //retrieve the data
  }

  public class FrameRoll implements Runnable {
     //do other stuff
  }
```

}

I'm calling a subactivity from the onCreate method in order to retrieve some gps data.The gps data are retrieved successfully.

```
public class GpsHandler extends Activity {

    //obtain location
enter code here
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                resultIntent.putExtra("location",
                        optimalLocation.toString());

              setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
```

}

When i try to call the subactivity from the inner class (frameroll) the sub activity runs normally but the method onActivityResult in ExperimentVIew is never called,so i don't get any data back.

```
public class ExperimentView extends Activity implements OnClickListener,{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      //Other stuff
      //Call the gpshandler activity
      gpsCall();
    }

    public void gpsCall() {
     if (gpsEnabled.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {

        Intent gpsHandler = new Intent(ExperimentView.this,
                GpsHandler.class);
        startActivityForResult(gpsHandler,
                GPSHANDLER_ACTIVITY_RETURN);

       }
  }
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     //retrieve the data
  }

  public class FrameRoll implements Runnable {
     gpsCall();
  }
```

}

I've tried different stuff which included implementing `onActivityResult` in the nested class,trying to do something like `ExperimentView.this.startActivityForResults()`,I printed the callingActivity in the gpshandler and it was the ExperimentView.

Every method i tried just failed.The onActivityResult is called only when the subactivity was called from `onCreate`.Does anynone know what should i do?

Thanx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onActivityResult` is called once your called-activity is finished. Therefore, you need to call `finish();` after setting result. For example:

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

*Make sure you are `GpsHandler` class complies with the correct implementation of **Activity** as it doesn't seem to override **onCreate** and/or other methods.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add finish(); but i have it on my code.So this doesn't solve anything.My main problem is that when the same thing is called on onCreate it wokrs perfectly.When it's called from the inner class the onActivity is not called

Comment: It depends, if your runnable is running on UI-thread then it should definitely work. Show me how you are executing your runnable

Comment: Here it is the inner class.The gpscall is in the bottom
http://pastebin.com/Vxw68F4U